# Principled Volume not working

Tags: lighting, volumetrics

As a beginner I am trying to follow a tutorial and learn by doing.
My principle Volume doesnt work the way it is inteded to. Everything above 0 density makes everything appear white. I have searched for this particular issue but couldnt find a solution to it.

It should look like this:
[image]

But instead looks like this:
[image]

Any input?
The lighting in general is giving me trouble, but this one i am unable to fix after tinkering for 2 hours.

Updated file link: [Blender File](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1mxynvxtzrntxis/AAAsxlwTsqROalCsFi0_PKVca?dl=0)

Comment: Hello, your link doesn't work, please use another platform, for example https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Fixed the link. Thank you.

Comment: pls add the link to the tutorial as well - thx

Answer (score 1):

So just matching your reference setup:

1. I removed the two extra lights, leaving just the area backlight with it's position and rotation straightened out.
2. I moved everything closer and scaled down the logo and volume objects.
3. Then I set the volume density to 0.64 to match the reference setup and tweaked the area light strength to match.

[image: Volumetrics]

So that should be a good starting point. The main problems with your setup were:

- The volume is too big, the reference is only one or two meters between objects.
- The extra sun light is so bright it is blowing out the entire volume. Based on the reference setup, you wouldn't even want a sun since it will add light to the entire volume.

Alternatively:

1. Delete the sun and spot lights
2. Turn up the strength on the area light and move it closer

[image: Alternate setup]

Answer (score 0):

Your sun light is much too strong, lower it down to something like 4. Also don't forget to increase the *End Distance* of the volumetrics in the *Render* panel, or it will be cut off:

[image]